# Certain apps on Mac OS Big Sur crash after upgrading from Catalina

Tags: mac, crash, big-sur, emacs

After upgrading from Mac OS 10.15.x (Catalina), certain apps and audio plugins suddenly started crashing with memory allocation errors. Reinstalling the OS did nothing and my searches on the Internet didn't seem to bring up anything useful.
Interestingly enough, in all of the crashlogs, the `libsystem_malloc.dylib`, `libsystem_c.dylib`, `libsystem_pthread.dylib`, `com.apple.quartzcore` are mentioned.
I am at a loss what to do and where to look next.
Thanks for any help!

Here are the crashlogs from two applications:

1. Emacs 27.1: https://pastebin.com/Tae4PMXz

- this is a binary build of Emacs 27.1 from Homebrew Cask with no modifications whatsoever. Works beautifully on Catalina 10.15 (same build).

2. Reaper: https://pastebin.com/TWaAVgux

- this application will crash as soon as the Structure VST plugin is loaded (you will see references to a subprocess in the log). Any recording app that loads this plugin will simply crash altogether.
- Again, works beautifully in Catalina 10.15, same build, same apps, same plugin version.

Comment: 1. Please upload two or more **full** crash logs via http://www.pastebin.com or equivalent service and add links to them in your question. 2. Have you run Disk First Aid on your boot volume? 3. Have you run Apple Hardware Diagnostics on your machine?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Apart from Emacs 27.0.1, which other "certain apps and audio plugins" crash? Are they apps you installed or system apps?

Comment: I note  that emacs has. 10.14 in its name where is it installed from? Also emacs 27.0.1 is not a normal version it does not match an official release https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/history.html so perhaps is a special build only for mojave

Comment: Thanks for the PasteBin suggestion. I uploaded two crashlogs there and provided the links in my original post. The version of Emacs is 27.1, not 27.0.1, apologies for that! I don't know where the 10_14 comes from, but this is certainly a binary build of the latest official version (from home-brew cask).